# How to bind a combo box's selected item with respect to its ID not the object itself?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xaml, data-binding, combobox

Consider the following markup (the last three labels are only for developing purposes so I that I can verify that the binding is doing what I think it is).

```
<ComboBox x:Name="TimeFrame"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          ItemsSource="{Binding TimeFrames}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Order.TimeFrame}"
          SelectionChanged="Combox_OnSelectionChanged" />
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Order.TimeFrame.Name}"></Label>
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Order.TimeFrame.Id}"></Label>
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Order.TimeFrameId}"></Label>
```

Everything works as supposed to, the changed option gets updated to the database and is restored correctly. All the labels are populated as expected. One thing that's wrong is that the selected item in the combo box isn't set properly. Since I can see that it's bind right, I assumed that the object comparison fails because the one stored in the order is a copy of the one in the combo box **but not the same instance**.

I resolved it using partial class on the time frames as follows.

```
public partial class TimeFrame
{
  public override bool Equals(object input)
  {
    TimeFrame comparee = input as TimeFrame;
    return comparee != null && comparee.Id == Id;
  }

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    return base.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

Sure enough, it works, which furthermore suggests that my conclusion is correct. Now I have two questions.

1. Is there a way to make the comparison from the markup (i.e. without overriding the equality check)?
2. Should I be concerned that the comparison fail due to those objects being different instances ([code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) risk)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Selector` and its descendants don't like, when non-null `SelectedItem` is not in `ItemsSource`.

Assuming, that you are working with view models, it is better to synchronize `Order.TimeFrame` with `TimeFrames`, when loading your view models. That is:

```
if (Order.TimeFrame != null)
{
    Order.TimeFrame = TimeFrames.SingleOrDefault(_ => _.Id == Order.TimeFrame.Id);
}
```

This also will correctly handle the case, when `Order.TimeFrame.Id` is not in `TimeFrames` ids.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a property for the SelectedTimeFrame and bind to it.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="TimeFrame"
      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
      ItemsSource="{Binding TimeFrames}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTimeFrame }"
      SelectionChanged="Combox_OnSelectionChanged" />
```

In the property setter update the Order.TimeFrame.